# Error:(58, 27) error: cannot access zzanb class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanb not found

Tags: java, android

This Is My Error In Android
I had read all the answers about this error and error corrections to work but I love Darm.dvstan If Myshm.ba guide grateful thanks

Error:

> (58, 27) error: cannot access zzanb
>   class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanb not found

My build.gradle(project:chatting)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And My Build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "firebasechat.asus.example.com.chatting"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'



    //New Add
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.6.1'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'(Not Work)
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.6.1'
    //compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.1.1' (Not Work)



    //New Add
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'(Not Work)
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'(Not Work)
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'(Not Work)
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'(Not Work)
    //compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.4.4@aar'(Not Work)
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please Help Me Because The Application Is Necessary

Comment: FireBase Error: cannot access zzanb class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanb not found .This time I tried, but it is impossible.